# Why does this JSON.parse() evaluation result in an error?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Why does running:

```
JSON.parse("{ Facet : 'asdf' }");
```

result in the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 1(…)`?

Comment: not quoted property and wrong quotes single instead of double.

Comment: In the future, you should check your json at jslint to make sure that it is valid prior to asking.

Comment: Geez - getting multiple down votes for such an innocent question - Seems like whoever down voted is a pretty crabby individual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key and value `(if a string)` pairs should always be enclosed inside double quotes `""`. Otherwise it is not a valid JSON string.

```
JSON.parse("{Facet:'asdf'}")  // with escaping
```

supposed to be

```
JSON.parse("{\"Facet\":\"asdf\"}")  // without escaping
```

or

```
JSON.parse('{"Facet":"asdf"}')
```

If the value is of type `Boolean` or `Number` or `null`, then it need not be enclosed in double quotes.

No double quotes are needed for values for the following types

```
JSON.parse('{"Facet": 100}')
JSON.parse('{"Facet": true}')
JSON.parse('{"Facet": null}')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{Facet:'asdf'}
```

is not a valid JSON string. The following is:

```
{"Facet": "asdf"}
```

Answer (score 0):

They keys have to be quoted too.
Ff you encode data to json by code (e.g: php array to json), it should do this for you already